# Using 3d array outside a function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function in which I make a 3D array and fill in all the values. I also have to pass a pointer to the function which will assign the memory location of the 3D array to that function so that it can be used outside of that function. Currently, I am doing something which does not seem to work, can someone guide me to the best possible resolution?

```
int (*arr)[4];

void assign_3D(int (*arr)[4]) 
{
    int local[2][3][4]; //probably we should pass *local?
    memset(local, 0, sizeof(int)*2*3*4);    // fill the local array with numbers

    arr = local; 
}

printf("%d\n", arr[1][2][3]);
```

I know I have written horrible code above. But I am learning :).

Comment: You don't want to pass pointers to local storage. It's reclaimed when it goes out of scope. Use `malloc (...)`, static storage, etc. instead.

Comment: Do you need to allocate on stack or heap?

Comment: Do you need to fill the local array with numbers and then copy content of the local array to the array passed as an argument? It would be easier to put numbers directly in the array passed as an argument without using the local array.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @JanWrobel any which way will do. I just need to take care that I find the first dimension of the array inside the function only.

Comment: @self: there is no restriction on that, but I think I should use heap because my array size could be large and the http context is called again and again, so allocating on stack might affect performance? Is there any specific advantage of allocating on stack?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to assign arrays. You are also using the wrong type for the argument (`int (*)[5]` is not what a `int [2][3][4]` decays into, use `int (*)[3][4]` as the argument type). Once you have the correct type, you can use `memcpy()` to do the assignment:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[2][3][4];

void assign_3D(int (*arr)[3][4]) {
    int local[2][3][4];
    memset(local, 0, sizeof(local));   //pass local here, because it is not a pointer but an array. Passing *local would only initialize the first element of the array, i. e. the first 2D slice of it.
    // fill the local array with numbers

    memcpy(arr, local, sizeof(local));
}

int main() {
    assign_3D(arr);
    printf("%d\n", arr[1][2][3]);
}
```

But you can also return a newly allocated array from your function:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int arrayType[2][3][4];

arrayType* create_3D() {
    arrayType* result = malloc(sizeof(*result));    //here we need to dereference because result is a pointer and we want memory for the array, not the pointer.
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(*result));
    (*result)[1][2][3] = 7;    // fill the local array with numbers

    return result;    //that's easy now, isn't it?
}

int main() {
    arrayType* array = create_3D();
    printf("%d\n", (*array)[1][2][3]);

    free(array);    //cleanup
}
```

---

Edit:
You mention that the size of the first dimension is not know before the function is run. In that case, you have to use the `malloc()` approach, but a bit differently:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int sliceType[3][4];

sliceType* create_3D(size_t* firstDimSize) {
    *firstDimSize = 2;
    size_t arraySize = *firstDimSize*sizeof(sliceType);

    sliceType* result = malloc(arraySize);
    memset(result, 0, arraySize);

    result[1][2][3] = 7;    // fill the local array with numbers

    return result;
}

int main() {
    size_t firstDim;
    sliceType* array = create_3D(&firstDim);
    printf("%d\n", array[1][2][3]);

    free(array);    //cleanup
}
```

Comment: problem with this is, in my program I find the first dimension of arr (=2) inside the assign_3D function only.

Comment: Added a section to specifically address this issue.

Comment: Very bad, not even one example compiles, without errors.

Comment: @self. Everything compiles now.

Answer (score -1):

There are two different ways to allocate a 3D array. You can allocate it either as a 1D array of pointers to a (1D array of pointers to a 1D array). This can be done as follows:

```
 int dim1, dim2, dim3;
 int i,j,k;
 int *** array = (int ***)malloc(dim1*sizeof(int**));

        for (i = 0; i< dim1; i++) {

         array[i] = (int **) malloc(dim2*sizeof(int *));

          for (j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {

              array[i][j] = (int *)malloc(dim3*sizeof(int));
          }

        }
```

Sometimes it is more appropriate to allocate the array as a contiguous chunk. You'll find that many existing libraries might require the array to exist in allocated memory. The disadvantage of this is that if your array is very very big you might not have such a large contiguous chunk available in memory.

```
const int dim1, dim2, dim3;  /* Global variables, dimension*/

#define ARR(i,j,k) (array[dim2*dim3*i + dim3*j + k])
int * array = (int *)malloc(dim1*dim2*dim3*sizeof(int));
```

To access your array you just use the macro:

```
ARR(1,0,3) = 4;
```

Comment: I like the second example but you should really consider using a function with a pointer parameter, instead of the macro, which is not very useful because it is using a predefined name and globals.

Comment: the macro above is very error prone. It won't work correctly if you use it like ARR(i, i + 1, i + 3)

Comment: Macro should parenthesize each use of its arguments to avoid this. Preferably use an inline function instead of macro.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not yet understood the full power of C-style arrays. You don't need to go through the hassle of allocating either pointer arrays or calculating the offset into the array all by yourself. The compiler can do this for you, you just have to provide it with the correct type.